# Get posts id in array by meta value and key

Tags: array

How to get all posts ids that has a meta key and value.

```
$meta_key = 'hide_rss';
$meta_value = 'yes';

$post_ids = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `meta_key`, `meta_value`, and `fields` parameters.

Example using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/): (Take note though, `get_posts()` ignores or doesn't include *sticky posts*.)

```
$meta_key = 'hide_rss';
$meta_value = 'yes';

$post_ids = get_posts( [
    'meta_key'   => $meta_key,
    'meta_value' => $meta_value,
    'fields'     => 'ids',
] );
```

Or using `new WP_Query()`:

```
$meta_key = 'hide_rss';
$meta_value = 'yes';

$q = new WP_Query();
$post_ids = $q->query( [
    'meta_key'   => $meta_key,
    'meta_value' => $meta_value,
    'fields'     => 'ids',
] );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters for other possibilities, or advanced meta query.