# Is there another way to retrieve a post_id from post_meta other than a SQL query?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I'd like to retrieve the `post_id` from `wp_post_meta` with a unique `meta_key` and `meta_value`. I've tried `WP_Query` but no values are returned and I'm unable to retrieve the `post_id`'

```
$post_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_key' => 'key',
    'meta_value' => 'value',
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $post_query->posts, 'ID' );

return $post_ids;
```

A similar post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067286/how-to-get-the-product-id-from-a-meta-key-and-a-meta-value-in-woocommerce) suggests that the only way is using a SQL query which differs to the suggestion from [Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300856/get-posts-id-in-array-by-meta-value-and-key).

Using a SQL query returns the `post_id`. If possible, I'd like to use `WP_Query` or a native function if there's one.

Comment: @bosco, I attempted your suggestion (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/409692/how-to-get-all-post-id-and-meta-value-using-meta-key-in-wp-postmeta-table) but no post_id is returned either

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `wp_list_pluck`?
In your query, you use `'fields' => 'ids'` so the return is an array of found post ids.

[From the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter):

> 'ids' – Return an array of post IDs.

Try returning `$post_query->posts;`

Comment: It only returns an empty array i.e. array(0) { }

Comment: Then your key or value are wrong or do not exist in the database.

Comment: the key and value match the strings in the database like for like.